# (Android java) Sending notification to calendar failed

Tags: java, android-notifications, android-calendar

I'm writing an app that has a button to send a text wrapped in a notification to google calendar and then the user's phone calendar will receive the notification from google calendar.

The strange thing is that my code works perfectly on Samsung Note 8 but fails on Samsung Note 4. How do I make this code to work on Note 8 and Note 4 (or preferrably on previous devices)?
For the record, I've made sure this Note 4 device is connected to the google calendar account so it should be able to receive notifications from google calendar.

**This is the code I tried. On button pressed, the following helper method is triggered.**

Note: Logcat reports the app stops at this line "Uri newReminder = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminder)". Android Studio says variable "newReminder" is never used.

```
public void setPreDefinedNotificationFor1Hour() {

        //Set notification
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, System.currentTimeMillis()+ 60*60*1000);  //Start in 1 hour
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, System.currentTimeMillis()+60*60*1000+60*60*1000);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, getResources().getString(R.string.Do_you_remember_this_word) + selectedListviewItemValue);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, false);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());

        Uri newEvent = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
        assert newEvent != null;
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(newEvent.getLastPathSegment())); // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri

        ContentValues reminder = new ContentValues();
        reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, ContentUris.parseId(newEvent));
        reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 0);
        reminder.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        Uri newReminder = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminder);

    }
```

I have requested permission in Manifest like so:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

    <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

I've requested permission programically like so:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == WRITE_PERMISSION){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Write Permission Failed");
                Toast.makeText(this,getString(R.string.External_storage_permission), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M) //This RequiresApi line has to be here or else this chunk of code will fail on Samsung Note 8
    private void requestWritePermission(){
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},WRITE_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error log regarding some SQLiteException:

```
05-03 15:26:43.177 9346-9346/com.example.android.dictionaryalmighty2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.dictionaryalmighty2, PID: 9346
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: null
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1284)
        at com.example.android.dictionaryalmighty2.UserInputHistory.i(:959)
        at c.e.a.a.l3.onClick(:428)
        at c.c.a.a$i.onCheckedChanged(:694)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:165)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:118)
        at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:76)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:123)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22546)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
05-03 15:26:43.202 3964-9593/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
05-03 15:26:43.202 3964-9593/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
05-03 15:26:43.202 3964-9593/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
05-03 15:26:43.807 13300-13300/? E/daemonapp: [MSC_Daemon]>>> WU:512 [0:0] [NameNotFoundException] sandPakage !!!!!
05-03 15:26:43.812 13300-13300/? E/daemonapp: [MSC_Daemon]>>> WU:512 [0:0] [NameNotFoundException] sandPakage !!!!!
05-03 15:26:44.132 9605-9605/? E/Zygote: v2
05-03 15:26:44.132 9605-9605/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-03 15:26:44.392 9624-9624/? E/Zygote: v2
05-03 15:26:44.392 9624-9624/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-03 15:26:44.537 9605-9605/? E/LWLocationManager: findLocationType() : cursor_location.moveToFirst() return false!!
05-03 15:26:45.372 9641-9641/? E/Zygote: v2
05-03 15:26:45.372 9641-9641/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
05-03 15:26:45.482 9641-9641/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.tencent.mm.coolassist.debugprovider
05-03 15:26:46.092 5639-5702/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 2 size : 0Kb duration : 1ms lastUpdatedAfter : 19642 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 410
05-03 15:26:49.057 3964-5789/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1123 [05-03 15:26:49.062]
05-03 15:26:50.132 5639-5702/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 2 size : 2Kb duration : 16ms lastUpdatedAfter : 4040 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 1366
05-03 15:26:51.577 3964-4185/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-03 15:26:51.702 3964-5138/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=326, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
05-03 15:26:51.702 3964-5138/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=327, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
05-03 15:26:51.732 9712-9712/? E/Zygote: v2
05-03 15:26:51.737 9712-9712/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
```

This is another error report regarding constraint violation:

```
05-03 15:25:56.157 5392-20740/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting service_kind=0 source=16 tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG requires_charging=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms source_version=201515000 required_network_type=0 flex_time=2672000 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService runtime=1588490756157 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} preferred_network_type=1 required_idleness_state=0 preferred_charging_state=1 last_runtime=0 period=5346000 task_type=0 job_id=-1 user_id=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
    Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
        (UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067))
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:919)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1609)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
        at apnp.a(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):76)
        at apne.a(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):173)
        at apne.a(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):21)
        at apne.a(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):167)
        at apjn.run(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):8)
        at ssd.b(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):12)
        at ssd.run(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at sye.run(:com.google.android.gms@201515015@20.15.15 (040300-306758586):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Update: Here are the dependencies I'm using**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

//Upper part omitted for privacy


    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {

        //applicationId omitted for privacy

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.sachinvarma:EasyPermission:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.fibelatti:MaterialShowcaseView:2.1.0'

//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'    This line is commented out because it clashes with targetSdkVersion 29 and I've already migrated to Android X.

    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.teprinciple:updateapputils:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:6.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you list your dependencies in you grade file or did you already solve your issue? And you may want to have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/361) that could related

Comment: @Vall0n  Hi Vall0n. Thanks for asking and sorry for coming in late. My issue isn't solved yet. I've updated my post above with a list of my dependencies at the bottom. I also checked your provided link but I haven't been able to figure out anything from there. Perhaps you could look at my dependencies list?  Your link mentions a lot about crashlytics, but I'm not sure if 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.2' in my dependencies list is getting in the way.

Comment: Hi @Dean, no problem. Since the provided link is an [firebase android sdk issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk), I think the issue comes from one of the the firebase dependencies. I would remove the firebase dependencies (as far as possible) one by one and test it. Maybe you can track the issue down to one firebase dependency which causes the error.